# Should I try stop Implicit Conversion?

Tags: sql-server-2012, cardinality

I have a table that is in a database I am not allowed to edit as it belongs to a third party. They have a field with datatype Char(2) this fields holds the following values:

```
01
02
03
04
```

I also have several other tables both physical and temp that have this same field and values. I am working on making a massive table that combines data between these tables. However when I run the code with just selecting that field not doing anything to it the execution plan does an implicit conversion to int.

I do not care that the field is int as that makes more sense to me anyways but the execution plan also states that the conversion

```
"may affect cardinality estimate"
```

I am having issues with this code running slow and was thinking this might be the problem.

Should I try to find a way to stop the conversion or is it likely not causing my slow down?

Edit:
Extra info this column is used in joins

Let me know if you need more info.

Using SQL 2012

Comment: are you joining on this column? The implicit conversion would remove the ability to use indexes on that column. Posting your execution plan would allow everyone to judge if that is the culprit of your performance concern or not.

Comment: yes I am joining on that column. I am working on getting approval from my boss to post execution plan. They worry about data privacy a lot here.

Comment: You could create a new table with yours INT ID and the Char(2) column (like a domain table). You could turn this INT column like PK and FK in your others tables. So you will compare INT x INT in yours tables and Char(2) x Char(2) with this new table and the third party table. This could be work for you. (sorry about my english)

Comment: @RafaelMansurHaddad Thank you for this idea. I will work on this and see how that works for me.

Comment: Ok!! I hope that works! Let me know the results... (y)

Comment: This worked for me if you want to put it as an answer I will mark it as correct sir. Thank you for your help.

Comment: yeap..., good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new table with yours INT ID and the Char(2) column (like a domain table). 
You could turn this INT column like PK and FK in your others tables. So you will compare INT x INT in yours tables and Char(2) x Char(2) with this new table and the third party table. This could be work for you. (sorry about my english)